# Loading a moviedatabase txt file in Java and sorting it

Tags: java, arraylist

The goal of this project is to read a movie data base txt file, where each line in the file contains the name, year released, and associated actors for one movie. Each piece of information is separated by ‘/’ characters. The year is specified inside parentheses at the end of the movie name. I have already created an actor class, which stores a String firstname and a String lastname, and a movie class which holds all the above info about the movie. In the movieDataBase class, I need to load the .txt file, and split it in to the different components. I understand how to split the file in to different elements, I just don't know how to turn the string of associated actors into and arrayList of Actor objects. Sorry for the newbie question. My java book doesn't talk about it at all and I have been looking for the past 3 hours on the internet! Here's my code:

```
public class Actor {

private String firstName;
private String lastName;

public Actor(){
    firstName = "";
    lastName = "";
}

public Actor( String first){
    this (first, "");
}

public Actor( String first, String last){
    firstName = first;
    lastName = last;

}

public String getFirstName(){
    return firstName;
}

public void setFirstName( String first){
    firstName = first;
}

public String getLastName(){
    return lastName;
}

public void setLastName( String last){
    lastName = last;
}

public String toString(){
    return firstName + " " + lastName;
}
```

}

```
//new class

public class MovieDatabase 

public void loadDataFromFile( String aFileName) throws FileNotFoundException{
    //creating a scanner to read the file
    Scanner theScanner = new Scanner(aFileName);
    theScanner = new Scanner(new FileInputStream("cast-mpaa.txt"));

    while(theScanner.hasNextLine()){
    String line = theScanner.nextLine();
    String[] splitting = line.split("/");
    String movieTitle = splitting[0];
    filmActors.add(splitting[2]);
    //this is where I have issues
    ArrayList<Actor> associatedActors = new ArrayList<Actor>();
    for( String newActors : filmActors){


    }

    }
}
```

}

Comment: Please add sample data from your file.

Comment: what's the definition of Actor class?

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like:

```
for( String newActor : filmActors){
     associatedActors.add(new Actor(newActor));
}
```

This means with `new Actor` you are creating a new object instance of Actor and adding it to the array List that you created.

To Actor class, you are passing the actor name in constructor and that's how you are constructing the Actor object i assume.

Comment: @DaisyHenderson For the sorting part you should use a custom comparator on the Actor class list , after you populate it